# How to setup session for a site alias. PHP Apache2

Tags: php, apache, session, apache2, session-variables

I'm running php on an Apache2 server with virtual hosts.  I have 2 domains, let's say domain1.com and domain2.com (NOT subdomains)

domain2.com is a ServerAlias of domain1.com

The session on domain1.com is working just fine.  However, I can't get session variables to save on domain2.com.

I don't believe my session is saving, because it's not carrying over between pages. I set the variables on my index.php page. I can dump the session and see that it was initially set.  Then my index.php redirects to home.php where I have this at the top of home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); 
?>
```

I'm getting an empty array on home.php

My phpinfo() settings are exactly the same for my session information on the 2 domains.

I'm stuck, not sure if this is a php issue, or an apache setting. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701678/php-shared-sessions-across-domain

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how that post relates to mine. My main problem is that the session is either not saving or being wiped on my alias domain.  Unless I am looking at the problem wrong?

Comment: sessions in php are propagated via cookies, so if you are having problems between domains this is why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions in php are normally maintained in php by cookies. What you are probably seeing is the value of `session.cookie_domain` being set to your working domain set in the ini. Use ini_set or [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) before your session_start call to rectify.

Comment: I did a phpinfo on both domain1.com and domain2.com  the session.cookie_domain is 'domain1.com' on both of them. Are you saying that I should set it to domain2.com when I'm on domain2.com?

Comment: that is the case the browser wont send domain1.com cookies to domain2.com

Comment: Ok so if I understand this correctly, my `session.cookie_domain` is set to domain1.com for both domain1.com and domain2.com however, domain2.com is saving the session in a place it can't access?  If that is correct, then I need something like this at the top of my page?`if($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]=='domain2.com'){ ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "domain2.com");}
session_start();`

Comment: It would've been too easy had it worked.  Does the code need to be at the top of every page, or just the initial page?  And I put the code on a page and did a phpinfo() call right after, and it's still showing `session.cookie_domain` as domain1.com  I feel like I'm missing something here...

Comment: After hours of beating my head against the desk, I figured it out. In my virtual host I was setting cookie_domain.  So it seems that no matter what I did in the php, the next time it would be overwritten by the server and essentially start a new session.  So I took that out of the virtual host and put this at the top of all my pages: `if($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]=='domain1.com'){
 ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "domain1.com");
}else{
 ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "domain2.com");
 
}

session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

Another option that worked for me: is to force the name of the session:

```
session_name("myWebsite");
session_start();
```