# Is it possible to share sessions across different domains in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-2.7

I need the same session in *www.domain1.com* and *www.domain2.com*.
Both domains use the same Symfony app.
All the examples I found ([PHP Shared Sessions across Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701678/php-shared-sessions-across-domain)) work only for subdomains (**.mysite.com*), but I have two different domains.

Is it possible to share the session across different domains in Symfony2?

Answer (score 3):

You can store session e.g. in **Redis** or **Memcache**. This can be configured under

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        storage_id: ~
        handler_id: ~
```

Thus session data will be accessible by both of your domains under the same app.

Some useful links:

- [Storing Symfony2 sessions in memcached](https://gist.github.com/K-Phoen/4327229)
- [Storing sessions in memcache with Symfony2 and PHP](http://awesomism.co.uk/storing-sessions-in-memcache-with-symfony2-and-php/)
- [Symfony2 Redis Session Handler](http://athlan.pl/symfony2-redis-session-handler/)